# Copy Document/Page excluding field/column or setting new value

Tags: events, versioning, uniqueidentifier, kentico

I'm using version 8 of Kentico and I have a custom document/page that has a unique numeric identity field, unfortunately this data from an existing source and because I cannot set the primary key ID of the page's coupled data when using the API I was forced to have this separate field.

I ensure the field is new and unique during the `DocumentEvents.Insert.Before` event using `node.SetValue("ItemIdentifier", newIdentifier);` if the the node's class name matches, etc. So Workflow is handled as well I also implemented the same method for `WorkflowEvents.SaveVersion.Before`.

This works great when creating a new item, whoever if we attempt to Copy an existing node the source `Identifier` remains unchanged. I was hoping I could exclude the field from being copied, but am as yet to find an example of that.

So I went ahead and implemented a solution to ensure a new identifier is created when a node is being copied by handling the `DocumentEvents.Copy.Before` and `DocumentEvents.Copy.After`.

Unfortunately in my case the `e.Node` from these event args are useless, I could not for the life of me get the field modified, when I opened IlSpy I realized why, the node copy method grabs a fresh copy of the node from the database always! Hence rendering `DocumentEvents.Copy.Before` useless if you want to modify fields before a node is copied.

So I instead pass the identifier along in a `RequestStockHelper` that the Insert, further down the cycle, handles to generate a new identifier for the cloned node.

Unfortunately, unbeknownst to me, if we copy a published node, the value on the database is correct, but the NodeXML value of it is not.

This IMO sounds like a Kentico bug, it's either retaining the source node's NodeXML/version, or for some reason `node.SetValue("ItemIdentifier", newIdentifier);` is not working properly on the `WorkflowEvents.SaveVersion.Before` since it's a published and workflowed node.

Anyone come across a similar issue to this? Is there any other way I can configure a field to be a unique numeric identity field, that is not the primary key, and is automatically incremented when inserted? Or exclude a field from the copy procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a possible solution, could you create a new document in `DocumentEvents.Copy.Before` and copy the values over from the copied document, then cancel the copy event itself?

Comment: that could work, but I think I now realize the issue, my interpertration of the `WorkflowEvents.SaveVersion.Before`. I'm in the process of testing a solution, if that doesn't work I'll definitely give that one a shot. thank you.

Comment: as suspected, this was actually a problem of my interpretation of WorkflowEvents, I will post an answer with my solution.

Comment: thanks for the help I dug a bit deeper, and I believe I could use your cancellation method when `DocumentEvents.Copy.Before` and then again on `DocumentEvents.Insert.Before` if the identifier were 0/null, preventing having to pass identifiers along in the `RequestStock` between events.

Comment: as yours would have been a neater solution, you got dibs on the answer :D I may refactor to this later if need be.

Answer (score 0):

ok, turns out this is not a Kentico issue but the way versions are saved.

if you want to compute a unique value in `DocumentEvents.Insert.Before` you need to pass it along to `WorkflowEvents.SaveVersion.Before` because the node that is sent in the later is the same as the original from the former. e.g. whatever changes you do in the `Insert` node are not sent along to `SaveVersion`, you need to handle this manually.

So here's the pseudo code that handles the copy scenario and insert of a new item of compiled type `CineDigitalAV`:

```
protected override void OnInit()
{
    base.OnInit();

    DocumentEvents.Insert.Before += Insert_Before;
    DocumentEvents.Copy.Before += Copy_Before;
    WorkflowEvents.SaveVersion.Before += SaveVersion_Before;

}

private void Copy_Before(object sender, DocumentEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Node != null)
    {
        SetCopyCineDigitalIdentifier(e.Node);
    }
}

private void SaveVersion_Before(object sender, WorkflowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Document != null)
    {
        EnsureCineDigitalIdentifier(e.Document);
    }
}

private void Insert_Before(object sender, DocumentEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Node != null)
    {
        EnsureCineDigitalIdentifier(e.Node);
    }
}


private void SetCopyCineDigitalIdentifier(TreeNode node)
{
    int identifier = 0;
    if (node.ClassName == CineDigitalAV.CLASS_NAME)
    {
        identifier = node.GetValue<int>("AVCreation_Identifier", 0);

        // flag next insert to create a new identifier
        if (identifier > 0)
            RequestStockHelper.Add("Copy-Identifier-" + identifier, true);
    }
}


private void EnsureCineDigitalIdentifier(TreeNode node)
{
    int identifier = 0;
    if (node.ClassName == CineDigitalAV.CLASS_NAME)
    {
        identifier = node.GetValue<int>("AVCreation_Identifier", 0);
    }

    if (identifier == 0 || (identifier != 0 && RequestStockHelper.Contains("Copy-Identifier-" + identifier)))
    {
        // generate a new identifier for new items ot those being copied
        RequestStockHelper.Remove("Copy-Identifier-" + identifier);
        int newIdentifier = GetNewCineDigitalIdentifierAV(node.NodeSiteName);
        node.SetValue("AVCreation_Identifier", newIdentifier);

        // store the newidentifier so that saveversion includes it 
        RequestStockHelper.Add("Version-Identifier-" + identifier, newIdentifier);
    }
    else if (RequestStockHelper.Contains("Version-Identifier-" + identifier))
    {
        // handle saveversion with value from the insert
        int newIdentifier = ValidationHelper.GetInteger(RequestStockHelper.GetItem("Version-Identifier-" + identifier), 0);
        RequestStockHelper.Remove("Version-Identifier-" + identifier);

        node.SetValue("AVCreation_Identifier", newIdentifier);
    }
}
private int GetNewCineDigitalIdentifierAV(string siteName)
{
    return (DocumentHelper.GetDocuments<CineDigitalAV>()
                            .OnSite(siteName)
                            .Published(false)
                            .Columns("AVCreation_Identifier")
                            .OrderByDescending("AVCreation_Identifier")
                            .FirstObject?
                            .AVCreation_Identifier ?? 0) + 1;
}
```